# django request.user.is_authenticated is always true?

Tags: python, django

Can anyone tell me why in the following code I get redirected to yahoo.com instead of google.com?

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^$', initialRequest,))
```

view

```
def initialRequest(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://yahoo.com')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://google.com')
```

Comment: @RichardGreen has it. Without the parenthesis, you're essentially testing that the `is_authenticated` attribute, itself, has a value, and it does: a method.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `request.user.is_authenticated()` i.e. with brackets as it's a function?

#### For Django 1.10 +

`is_authenticated` is now an attribute (although it is being kept backwards compatible for now).

Comment: Update: For those who are migrating from py2 to py3. "2.0: Using User.is_authenticated() and User.is_anonymous() as methods will no longer be supported." - Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/

Answer (score 12):

As Richard mentioned is_authenticated is a function, so in your view it should be called like: `request.user.is_authenticated()`.

Because of django templating language there can be confusion, because calling this in a template makes it appear as a property and not a method.

`{{ user.is_authenticated}}`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Answer (score 4):

its changed again from Pull request [#216](https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider/pull/216).

now your problem is fixed, if you are using Django 2.0+, look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider/issues/218) is the same issues you had. so in Django 2.0+

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

is true!

Answer (score 2):

I've django 2.0, I tried this and works

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```