# how to determine the status of the user?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

is a function that defines the user logged in or not:
views.py:

```
def ajax_is_authenticated_check(request):
    """
    ajax check auth for like process and any
    """ 
    result = False

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            result = True

    data = {
        'is_authenticated': result
    }

    print(result)   #this is output to console

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

resulting function always returns "true". and output console "true".

it is not clear why, if the user has not entered, it still comes back the "true"

Comment: possible duplicate of [django request.user.is\_authenticated is always true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316666/django-request-user-is-authenticated-is-always-true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `is_authenticated` is a method, not a property.

Code should look like this

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated(): # note the ()
            result = True
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django 1.10 onwards `is_authenticated` is a property and you can use `request.user.is_authenticated`.

For version below 1.10 you need to use `request.user.is_authenticated()` in views.

Note: In templates for all versions you can use `request.user.is_authenticated`.