# Users are not being authenticated after login

Tags: django, django-authentication

This is my first time working with Django and I'm trying to create a simple login page. I would like the login page to be located at the base URL (index) of the site and then redirect to "assignments/" with "assignments/" and all other pages on the site only being accessible if the user is logged in. When I try to view if the user is authenticated (using "request.user.is_authenticated"), the view handles the user as if he/she is not logged in.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/login.html')


def assignments(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        assignment_list = Assignment.objects.all()
        context_dict = {'assignments': assignment_list}
        return render(request, 'mainapp/assignments.html', context_dict)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You must login first")

def show_assignment(request, assignment_name_slug):
    try:
        context_dict = {}
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(slug=assignment_name_slug)
        context_dict['assignment'] = assignment
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['assignment'] = None
    return render(request, 'mainapp/projectpage.html', context_dict)



def user_login(request):
    information.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                dj_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('assignments'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else: 
            print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")   
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You must login first")
```

application urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.assignments, name='assignments'),
    url(r'^(?P<assignment_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
        views.show_assignment, name='show_assignment')
]
```

project urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.login, name="login"),
        url(r'^assignments/', include('mainapp.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

login.html

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="{% url 'assignments' %}" class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="bg-info border-info btn btn-primary"/>
              </form>
```

MIDDLEWARE

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Are you sure `dj_login(request, user)` is working ?. Also please post your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Nope it's not a method it's [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#using-user-is-authenticated-and-user-is-anonymous-as-methods)

Comment: Are you using Django's Session and Authentication Middleware? These middleware's connect the session id in the cookie to a user in your database

Comment: @at14 I'm currently not using any sessions. Would sessions need to be implemented in order for "request.user.is_authenticated" to work?

Comment: Is your admin site working?

Comment: @itzMEonTV yes, the admin site is working

Comment: One thing that I have been reading is that settings.py needs a login_url specified, however, I'm not sure what that url should be given that my login page is on the base page

Comment: Do a print `request.user` on bottom of `dj_login(request, user)`.

Comment: @itzMEonTV I'm not sure how to go about seeing the results of the print statement. Also, for some reason, not sure what I may or may not have changed, but the is_authenticated seems to be working, however, it is also allowing people who are not logged in to view pages.

Comment: You don't seem to have anything that calls your `user_login` view which is the one that actually does the logging in.

Comment: First .. `user_login` and `login`, You used `login` which is a view which render a template
Second .. `from django.contrib.auth.views import login` use this view if your login is pretty forward
Third .. `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required` is a decorator to easily use instead of `user.is_authenticated` 
so try to 1- merge `user_login` with `login` or 2 - use django views `login`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot () sign inside 'assignments' method

try :

```
request.user.is_authenticated():
```

Comment: I believe it no longer matters --> 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316666/django-request-user-is-authenticated-is-always-true